# Retrieving ARB subscriptions with Authorize.Net API

Tags: authorize.net, recurring-billing

Is it possible using the APIs provided by Authorize.Net to retrieve or search for a list of automated recurring billing (ARB) subscriptions? The high-level APIs only appear to allow for creating, updating, or cancelling existing ARB subscriptions. A quick look at the advanced integration method (AIM) APIs do not indicate (clearly) if this is possible.

I have already written an implementation centered around HttpWebRequest/Response, ASP.NET POST hijacking, SGML parsing, and XML DOM traversal, but I would prefer a proper solution that doesn't rely on data scraping (what I am currently doing). That, and the current implementation is a bit slow.

If it's not already apparent, I am utilizing C# and the Authorize.Net ARB/CIM API, although I am really looking for a (better) solution that utilizes any available API.

References:

http://developer.authorize.net/api/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. They do not currently offer this through an API or through their control panel.